# How to run Javascript in iMacros

Tags: javascript, imacros

How can I run javascript code in iMacros. Can I run:

```
function pageScroll() {
        window.scrollBy(0,50); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
        scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',100); // scrolls every 100 milliseconds
}

<body onLoad="pageScroll()">
```

There was one question here on stackoverflow, but I instructions were not helpful enough also iMacros editor has code generator and I used javascipt option, but still same result.

Comment: That was the question I was talking about. I tried that approach but it doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this pseudo-URL:

```
URL GOTO=javascript:{function<SP>pageScroll(){window.scrollBy(0,50);/*horizontal_and_vertical_scroll_increments*/scrolldelay=setTimeout("pageScroll()",100);/*scrolls_every_100_milliseconds*/}pageScroll();}
```